# Recursive SQL Query not give correct results

Tags: sql-server, recursive-query

Using SQL Server, I have a table called Prerequisites with two columns, course_id and prereq_id. Example: my Prerequisites table looks like:
[image]

I need a query that will every prereq_id needed for the course_id.. something like this: [image]

So far I have been able to get a partial list, but it also adds a row with identical group_id/course_id.. example: for BIO-102 it gives values MATH-120, BIO-101, and BIO-102, the last one not needed.. and it does not list any prereq for BIO-101, here is my current query:

```
    ;WITH CTE
    AS  
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            M1.course_id group_id,
            M1.course_id
FROM Prerequisites M1
    LEFT JOIN Prerequisites M2
        ON M1.course_id = M2.prereq_id
        WHERE M2.course_id IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            C.group_id,
            M.prereq_id
        FROM CTE C
            JOIN Prerequisites M
                ON C.course_id = M.course_id
    ) 
    SELECT * FROM CTE ORDER BY group_id
```

and results are:
[image]

Comment: Remove `LEFT JOIN` before `UNION ALL`

Comment: I removed the "WHERE M2.course_id IS NULL" and got correct format

Answer (score 0):

It looks like simple recursive query is enough.
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06336/1/0)

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (course_id varchar(50), prereq_id varchar(50));

INSERT INTO @T (course_id, prereq_id) VALUES
('BIO-101', 'MATH-120'),
('BIO-102', 'BIO-101'),
('BIO-103', 'BIO-102'),
('BIO-103', 'MATH-130');

WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        course_id AS group_id
        ,prereq_id AS course_id
    FROM @T

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        CTE.group_id
        ,T.prereq_id AS course_id
    FROM
        CTE
        INNER JOIN @T AS T ON T.course_id = CTE.course_id
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
ORDER BY group_id, course_id;
```

**Result**

```
+----------+-----------+
| group_id | course_id |
+----------+-----------+
| BIO-101  | MATH-120  |
| BIO-102  | BIO-101   |
| BIO-102  | MATH-120  |
| BIO-103  | BIO-101   |
| BIO-103  | BIO-102   |
| BIO-103  | MATH-120  |
| BIO-103  | MATH-130  |
+----------+-----------+
```